# secure nifi cluster on k8s with ingress login error: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname not verified

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to set up a nifi cluster (3 nifi pods and 3 zk pods) on k8s.
I've enabled:

1. ldap login authentication
2. data persistency
3. and an ingress for load balancing

nifi web server was started ok as I can see login screens when accessing the ingress url.
I can see nifi is started ok in each pod.

ldap authentication works for a short period when the entire cluster is still disconnected.
But after the cluster finishes synchronization, when I log in again, I run into this error:

An unexpected error has occurred

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname node-####.svc.cluster.local not verified: certificate: sha256/E7####.######TU= DN: CN=domain.com, OU=Crypto Certificates, OU=###, O=####, C=CA subjectAltNames: [*.domain.com, domain.com]

It seems that the ingress cannot authenticate the nifi node (node-####.svc.cluster.local) as it expects only from domain.com

I've tried to

1. set the following to false and force nifi to use http:

   nifi.remote.input.secure=false
   nifi.cluster.protocol.is.secure=false

and disable nifi.web.https.port, instead set nifi.web.http.port

2. my ingress yaml:

   ingress:

   enabled: true

   className: nginx

   annotations:

   ```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
   ```

   tls:

   ```
    - hosts:

      - nifi-cluster.domain.com

      secretName: ssl-certs
   ```

   hosts:

   ```
    - nifi-cluster.domain.com
   ```

   path: /

if there's no way to modify/generate a new certificate for the ingress,
is there any alternative solution to work around this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the TLS configuration from your ingress `tls: [].`

Also there is a [sample configuration steps](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/nifikop/tree/master/config/samples/keycloak-example) from official docs that you can try to modify the certificate being used by the cluster.

Comment: Thanks, I have to enable tls as required by organization and if I disable tls, I won't be able to access the nifi web UI (i.e. the canvas). I will check the other document you mentioned. Thanks.